# Powershell script skipping a step

Tags: powershell

This is on Windows 10

This may be a simple logic error on my part, I am relatively new to PowerShell...

My main script checks for if a user is logged on and if so calls another script that presents a form with a timer (script "readytoinstall_logoff.ps1" called on line 04). When the timer expires it issues a logoff command and closes the form and returns control to the main script. All good, except after the script called in line 04 below closes it is not executing line 05-06, it is jumping to line 12. I am trying to introduce a delay to allow time for the account to be logged off but it is not executing the sleep. (And before anyone says I will be replacing the "sleep" with a "while loop" later on, just trying to figure out why it is not getting executed.) Thanks!

```
01 if((quser /server:'localhost')){
02    Add-Content -Path $sLogFile -Value (quser /server:'localhost')
03    Add-Content -Path $sLogFile -Value "$(Get-Date -Format G) - User logon detected, calling 'Ready to install_logoff'"
04    & .\ReadyToInstall_logoff.ps1 -sAppName $sAppname -vAppVersion $vAppVersion -sLogfile $sLogFile -Timeout $TimeOut
05    Add-Content -Path $sLogFile -Value "$(Get-Date -Format G) - Sleeping 30 seconds to allow time to logoff"
06    Sleep -s 30
07    }
08    else
09    {
10    Add-Content -Path $sLogFile -Value "No user logon detected, continuing"
11    }
12
13
14
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine. Maybe the second script fails and causes the parent script to stop.

Try setting $ErrorActionPreference = continue

Comment: Well, the parent script does continue, it just seems to not execute the two lines of code immediately after the statement calling the other script.

Comment: I tried another option within the script that worked, so there must be something wrong with the method in which I close the form between the two functions. Need to dig into that real quick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, apparently I (stupidly) used two different methods of closing the other form, so I used the one that works in both locations and it is working fine now, which is GREAT!

Comment: Perhaps elaborate on the two different methods you used to close the forms - it may be useful to others

Comment: The actual issue was, the section that worked had a "form.close()" statement AFTER the logoff command, whereas the failing step had the form close before the logoff command. :-)